# Triggering Dag Using GCS create event without Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-composer

Is there a method to trigger cloud composer by listening to GCS create events without the use of cloud functions?

I came across this article: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf , however, I am working temporarily for a team that is not very technical. Hence, I'm trying to run workflow when a file is created in a certain bucket, with as minimum maintainability requrements as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Cloud Functions is the easiest way to trigger a DAG from a Cloud Storage Event. The other option is using [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes#code-samples) which seems to be more complex than the code showed in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf) you shared.

I've created Cloud Functions to trigger DAGs in Composer and the most complex step is only getting the ID of the Web Server.